# How to read the content of second html file in js file in LWC?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx

I have two html files in my LWC and one js file.

1. targetLwcComponent.html
2. targetLwcComponent.css
3. accountRelatedContacts.js-meta.xml
4. pdfGeneration.html

I have imported the html file in js file like this -

**import pdftemplate from './pdfGeneration.html';**

And I want to read the content of second html file but I am not able to read. I tried using querySelector and getElementById but it's not working.

**let content = pdftemplate.getElementById('container');
console.log(content.outerHTML);**

or

**let content = pdftemplate.querySelector('container');
console.log(content.outerHTML);**

Comment: Why you want to read the content, what you want to do with that content?

Comment: I guess you should check this, the use case of templates. [Render Multiple Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_render)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not what templates are used for, as stated by @itzmukeshy7; you can only use this mechanism to select which template you want to use, which is ideal for complicated layouts or components that would otherwise exceed the 128k maximum file size.

Instead, you have to query something that's already rendered in the DOM if you want to create a PDF. However, this is non-trivial, as you can't traverse child elements of a Lightning Component because of the nature of the [Shadow DOM](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom).

If you fully render HTML inside a component marked `lwc:dom="manual"`, you can freely examine its contents and perhaps use jspdf or another similar library to render a PDF, or even send the fragment to the server and have Apex use Flying Saucer to render the PDF. No matter what you do, though, using native components isn't the answer.